# Singleton pattern in Robocode

Tags: java, robocode

I was trying to implement singleton pattern in Robocode. But unfortunately, when new round starts, every time a new object (which is singleton) is created.

Do you know if it is possible to use singleton pattern in Robocode? If not, could you explain me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that Robocode is designed such that each robot is created via it's own ClassLoader, so unfortunately singletons wouldn't be possible except within a robot.